# $f\in L^1(K)$ implies $f\in L^\infty (K_0)$ and $\int_{K\setminus K_0}f\leq\delta$, $\delta>0$ and some $K_0$.

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $K\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ is a measurable set and $f\in L^1(K)$ with $f\geq 0$. For given $\delta>0$, is it possible to find a measurable set $K_0\subset K$ such that $f\in L^\infty (K_0)$ and $$\tag{1}\int_{K\setminus K_0}f\leq\delta$$

Remark: I can see that the set of all measurable subsets $K_0$ of $K$, for which $(1)$ is valid is non empty. What I cannot prove, is that for some $K_0$ satisfying $(1)$, we have that $f\in L^\infty (K_0)$.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: take $f_k:=f\chi_{\{f\leqslant k\}}$. Then $f_k\to f$ almost everywhere and by monotone convergence, in $L^1(K)$. And $f_k$ is bounded on $\{f\leqslant k\}$.

Comment: You are welcome.